# Invoking paintComponent with JApplet

Tags: java, swing, japplet

Hey I've created a simple Frame that displays the olympic rings but I try to port them to applet without any success. This is the code I'm running:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CirclesApplet extends JApplet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Container c;
public void init(){
    c = getContentPane();
    c.setSize(300, 300);
    c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawOval(65, 90, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.drawOval(95, 110, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(125, 90, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawOval(155, 110, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(180, 90, 50, 50);
    g.drawString("Olympic Rings", 120, 185);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *Always* use the `@Override` annotation before a method that you *think* that you might be overriding. If you did this, you would see that @camickr is correct, that there is no `paintComponent(...)` method for JApplets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

There is no paintComponent() method of a JApplet, JFrame or JDialog.

As you know for your other postings you override the paintComponent() method of a panel to do custom painting and then add the panel to the content pane.

A JApplet is no different, it also has a content pane.